# How to create a dynamic dependent dropdown menu using ipywidgets?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

I created a form with two drop down menu's:

My goal is to make one dropdown dependent on the other dropdown.

[This picture illustrates my goal and the current situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9k5G.png)

The sample code below can be run in Google Colab or Jupyter notebook to replicate the current situation.

```
#@title 
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, Label
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, Box, FloatText, Textarea, Dropdown, Label, IntSlider
import time
import pandas as pd

#Create DF
df = df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Dropdown_column', 'Float_column'])
df

# Layout
form_item_layout = Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='row',
    justify_content='space-between',
)


button_item_layout = Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='row',
    justify_content='center',
    padding = '5%'
)


# Independent dropdown item

drop_down_input = 'Dropdown_input_1'

drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=('Dropdown_input_1', 'Dropdown_input_2'))

def dropdown_handler(change):
    global drop_down_input
    print('\r','Dropdown: ' + str(change.new),end='')
    drop_down_input = change.new

drop_down.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')


# Dependent drop down

# Dependent drop down elements

dependent_drop_down_elements = {}
dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_1'] = ['A', 'B']
dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_2'] = ['C', 'D', 'E'] 

# Define dependent drop down

dependent_drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=(dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_1']))

def dropdown_handler(change):
    global drop_down_input
    print('\r','Dropdown: ' + str(change.new),end='')
    drop_down_input = change.new  
drop_down.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')



# Button

button = widgets.Button(description='Add row to dataframe')
out = widgets.Output()
def on_button_clicked(b):
    global df
    button.description = 'Row added'
    time.sleep(1)
    with out:
      new_row = {'Dropdown_column': drop_down_input, 'Float_column': float_input}
      df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
      button.description = 'Add row to dataframe'
      out.clear_output()  
      display(df)
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

# Form items

form_items = [         
    Box([Label(value='Independent dropdown'),
         drop_down], layout=form_item_layout),
    Box([Label(value='Dependent dropdown'),
         dependent_drop_down], layout=form_item_layout)
         ]

form = Box(form_items, layout=Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    border='solid 1px',
    align_items='stretch',
    width='30%',
    padding = '1%'
))
display(form)
display(out)
```

Is this possible? If so, can you explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting a `if` statement in your `dropdown_handler` function that checks if the value chosen in your independent dropdown is `Dropdown_input_1` or `Dropdown_input2`. Still in the `dropdown_handler`, you can then modify accordingly the `options` arguments to either `dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_1']` or `dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_2']`.

See code below:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, Label
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, Box, FloatText, Textarea, Dropdown, Label, IntSlider
import time
import pandas as pd

#Create DF
df = df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Dropdown_column', 'Float_column'])
df

# Layout
form_item_layout = Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='row',
    justify_content='space-between',
)


button_item_layout = Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='row',
    justify_content='center',
    padding = '5%'
)


# Independent dropdown item

drop_down_input = 'Dropdown_input_1'
drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=('Dropdown_input_1', 'Dropdown_input_2'))


# Dependent drop down
# Dependent drop down elements
dependent_drop_down_elements = {}
dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_1'] = ['A', 'B']
dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_2'] = ['C', 'D', 'E'] 

# Define dependent drop down

dependent_drop_down = widgets.Dropdown(options=(dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_1']))

def dropdown_handler(change):
    global drop_down_input
    print('\r','Dropdown: ' + str(change.new),end='')
    drop_down_input = change.new
    #If statement checking on dropdown value and changing options of the dependent dropdown accordingly
    if change.new=='Dropdown_input_2':
       dependent_drop_down.options=dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_2']
    elif change.new=='Dropdown_input_1':
        dependent_drop_down.options=dependent_drop_down_elements['Dropdown_input_1']
drop_down.observe(dropdown_handler, names='value')

# Button

button = widgets.Button(description='Add row to dataframe')
out = widgets.Output()
def on_button_clicked(b):
    global df
    button.description = 'Row added'
    time.sleep(1)
    with out:
      new_row = {'Dropdown_column': drop_down_input, 'Float_column': float_input}
      df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
      button.description = 'Add row to dataframe'
      out.clear_output()  
      display(df)
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

# Form items

form_items = [         
    Box([Label(value='Independent dropdown'),
         drop_down], layout=form_item_layout),
    Box([Label(value='Dependent dropdown'),
         dependent_drop_down], layout=form_item_layout)
         ]

form = Box(form_items, layout=Layout(
    display='flex',
    flex_flow='column',
    border='solid 1px',
    align_items='stretch',
    width='30%',
    padding = '1%'
))
display(form)
display(out)
```

As an example, this is what the output looks like when you pick `Dropdown_input_2` on the first widget:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The if statement helped me on the right way! I slightly adapted the code to make it more scalable: 
       
`if change['type'] == 'change':
      dependent_drop_down.options=dependent_drop_down_elements[change.new]`
     

Now, it keeps taking the right value from the dictionary list also if I increase the dictionary list.

Comment: Happy to hear! Consider marking your question as answered by clicking on the green tick next to my answer if you are satisfied with my answer. Thx!